# How to pass text from a textField to Google Search from an iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-search

I would like to pass a string to the Google search from my iOS app, so as to enable me to fetch the results in Safari.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: Swift Open Link in Safari  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945324/swift-open-link-in-safari

Comment: No, based on the String, I have to fetch results from google search

Comment: So, you don't want to display/fetch the results in safari, you simply want to somehow parse the query results (HTML) in your code, without displaying them?

Comment: Yes i want to display the results in the browser itself, which is exactly like using Google Search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var query = "hello world"
query = query.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
var url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" + query
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: url)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Replace query with your search string.

Answer (score 5):

If you use your own web view (which you specified in your comment *before* you changed it to something completly different), you could use the [`WKWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) and `URLRequest` to load and display the data.
Don't forget to escape the query string, something like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

func startSearch() {

    var textToSearch = "the answer to everything"
    // if there are spaces or other special characters,
    // you'll have to escape them:
    let allowedCharacters = NSCharacterSet.urlFragmentAllowed

    guard let  encodedSearchString  = textToSearch.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacters)  else { return }

    let queryString = "https://www.google.de/search?q=\(encodedSearchString)"
    guard let queryURL = URL(string: queryString) else { return }

    let myRequest = URLRequest(url:queryURL)
        webView.load(myRequest)
}
```

Comment: Thanks to one and all, Finally I have reached my target.